# How to test simple slope for interaction?

Tags: interaction

I am working with a dataset and found a significant interaction between a continuous and categorical (2 levels) predictor (DV is continuous--so the model is something like DV = b1 + b2 + b1*b2). How should I test the simple effect? To help visualize, let's say I have a graph, with my DV on y-axis, continuous predictor on x-axis, and two different lines: one for each level of my categorical predictor. How can I tell if those slopes are different from zero?

I don't know if it makes sense to dummy code one level and then look at the intercept to see if it is different from zero. Or, "split" the data and look at each categorical predictor separately. Any advice much appreciated. Thank you! (I am using R to analyze the data)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  If you have a categorical variable with 2 levels, then the t-statistic on the coefficient for that variable will tell you if it is different from zero.

Comment: my apologies! I have edited to try and be more clear.

Comment: If that's the case, then the t-statistic on the interaction term will tell you if the effect of the continuous predictor differs by the level of the categorical predictor